# Why does the Firebase web database read method .once have a .then method, but .on does not?

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, web

I've been trying to understand why the Firebase Web read method .once has the .then method and .on does not.

[Here's a link to the code reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)

[Here's a link to the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

From my understanding from reading the Firebase web docs the .once method has a .then() method so that it can return a promise to the data once it is retrieved, since the call to the database is asynchronous.

```
//Method to call
var readUserData = function (uid) {
    return firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var user = snapshot.val();
        return user;
    });
};

//How I call the method
readUserData(uid).then(function(userData){
    //Do things with the data
});
```

This is easily understandable and I am able to use the .then to wait for my data, and to continue on with synchronous actions once my data is got. It also makes sense that I can't return the data outside of .then, because the data will be undefined.

With the .on function I make a function like this:

```
function readAllJobData() {
    return firebase.database().ref('jobs').on('value', function(snapshot){
        var field, obj, jobArray = [];
        tempObj = Object.entries(snapshot.val()); // Gets the individual entries in the snapshot
        for(field in tempObj){
            obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempObj[field][1])); // Parses the JSON for each job and its data
            console.log(obj.name);
            jobArray.push(obj);
        }
        return jobArray;
    });

}
```

I cannot call the function like this,

```
readAllJobData().then(function(data){//use data});
```

Because .then() does not exist as a method for .on

And if I call the function like this,

```
var jobData = readAllJobData();
```

the callback function is returned - which does not have access to the gotten data like .once would, so an error is thrown.

Now when I create a function like this,

```
var readAllJobData = function() {
    var jobArr = [];
    firebase.database().ref('jobs').on('value', function(snapshot){
        var field, obj;
        tempObj = Object.entries(snapshot.val()); // Gets the individual entries in the snapshot
        for(field in tempObj){
            obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempObj[field][1])); // Parses the JSON for each job and its data
            console.log(obj.name); //Logs what I wanted first
            jobArr.push(obj);
        }

    });
    console.log("jobArr",jobArr); //Logs what I wanted second
    return jobArr; //returns expected array
};
```

And I call it like this,

```
var jobData = readAllJobData();
```

the console outputs 'obj.name' correctly, then outputs 'jobArr' correctly, and jobData is assigned the array I needed. This seems odd because if .once was used in this scenario, this would not work.

To reiterate the question, why does .then only exist for the .once method, and not the .on method also? It would seem to me that both methods should have promises to the data that they are asynchronously retrieving. This makes me unsure of how I should be making calls to the database with .on. Do I have to hardcode(make the call and use the callback to call a specific method) any read methods using .on, or is there a better/preferred way to make a read with .on?

Also, why does the .on method appear as if it is executing synchronously, as depicted in the closest example above? Could the function seem to work synchronously because the call to the database is so fast, and there is so little data(I'm only returning 2 records at the moment, not sure if this makes a difference)?

Apologies for any unclear questions, statements or code, and thanks ahead of time for any insights you might have!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase but my guess is that `on` works like an event listener. You attach it and your function runs _every time_ the event happens. `then` is like a Promise which only resolves _once_. Promise resolving is not repeatable like an event can be.

Comment: @Frank Van Puffelen I'm curious as to how I should be running my .on method still. So from what I understand from the question that you marked as duplicate, the .once is run only once, and therefore needs a promise, and .on doesn't need a promise because it returns a reference to the data. Does this mean that I can treat my .on method code as synchronous(with checks on the first data retrieval) because the data will be updated by the reference eventually? I'm trying to not over-analyze, yet figure out if I should treat .on as asynchronous or synchronous. Thanks a ton Frank.

Comment: Both `on()` and `once()` trigger asynchronous behavior. The difference is that `once()` can actually complete, since you're saying that it's done after it gets an event. Neither `once()` not `on()` **needs** a promise. But since `once()` can only fire once, it **can** implement the contract of a promise.